# How to create WCF architecture with MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a separate WCF project and it is hosted in IIS. Now I want to consume it in my MVC application. I want a clean architecture.

My approach is - I am generating proxies inside MVC application in a folder called proxies. Is it cleaner or better I should create a separate class library from proxies and reference class library inside MVC application?

Please suggest cleaner approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the client proxies into a separate assembly (class library) and reference that project from the MVC project. In general I think its good practice to have assembly separation for the entire WCF implementation.

Specifically, I would have separate assemblies for the following components:

- Service and data contracts
- Services
- Business/ORM engines etc
- Service hosts
- Client proxies
- Client applications